# Redis- Retrieving value from redis-cli

Tags: caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using the .net core application to set a value in cache. When I try to retrieve the value using `hgetall "keyname"` I'm getting

```
"absexp"
"637648117989920"
"data"
"sldexp"
"100000000"
```

I could see the value of `absexp` and `sldexp`. But what is the best way to view the json data which is stored in data using redis-cli.

Note: I tried using `Azure Cache` extension in visual studio code for testing locally but is there a way to test in redis-cli as I cannot access other test environments from `Azure cache` extension and fetch this value?

Comment: Vanilla Redis (the one I suppose you are using) does not support JSON datatypes. What you are retrieving is type [Hash](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes). And that is the only way to see it using redis-cli. They are not __pretty printed__. If you want to use pure JSON inside your redis, take a look at [Redis JSON Storage](https://redis.com/redis-best-practices/data-storage-patterns/json-storage/)

Comment: @usuario - When I checked the type of data, it is returning as Hash. I'm using `StackExchange.Redis `. Previously it used to return the data when I used `hgetall` (Not the nicest format but was able to read).